# keyword colors in emacs on terminal

Tags: emacs, putty, secure-crt

I am connecting to a server through SecureCRT and am using command line emacs (not X11). Is there a way to get color? In particular, when I code I would like emacs to color keywords etc.  Currently everything is either black or white.

Comment: What is the value of your `TERM`, obtained with `echo $TERM`? Emacs under xterm-like terminals does colors, so you can try starting it with `TERM=xterm emacs`.

Comment: just got it - emulation type has to be linux not vt100

Comment: @user4815162342 Please submit a proper answer so that Alex can mark it as correct.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, I've now done so. I didn't want to write an answer in the first place because my answer felt too question-y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the value of the `TERM` environment variable, obtained with `echo $TERM`. Emacs under xterm-like terminals does colors, so you can try starting it with `TERM=xterm emacs`.